# Selenium web driver unable to automatically play video

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to test if the video player on my website works. 
I tried this, but the video player does not start playing the video.

```
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp");
//sleep for the page to entirely load
Thread.sleep(10000L);
String videoPlayerPath = "document.getElementById(\"video1\")";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript(videoPlayerPath + ".play()");
```

`document.getElementById("video1").play()` works on the browser console, but I'm not able to get it working via Selenium

Answer (score 0):

use `WebDriverWait`instead of `Thread.sleep` to load the content and use the JS part in one line like this

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('video1').play();");
```

Comment: I don't see any errors on the console which can help debug this.

Comment: then use try-catch whole program if any exception is occurring